# Pandas: Return a new Dataframe with specific non continuous column selection

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 85 columns and something like 10.000 rows.
The first column is `Shrt_Desc` and the last `Refuse_Pct`
The new data frame that I want has to have `Shrt_Desc`, then leave some columns out and then include in series `Fiber_TD_(g)` to `Refuse_Pct`
I use:

```
dfi_3 = food_info.loc[:, ['Shrt_Desc', 'Fiber_TD_(g)':'Refuse_Pct']]
```

but it gives a syntax error.
Any ideas how can I achieve this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borrowing the main idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10677896/5276797):

```
pd.concat([food_info['Shrt_Desc'], food_info.ix[:, 'Fiber_TD_(g)':]], axis=1)
```