# How to select dataframe columns with lists and ranges combined

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Please consider this df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2], 'b':[1,2], 'c':[1,2], 'd':[1,2], 'e':[1,2], 'f':[1,2], 'g':[1,2], 'h':[1,2]})

   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
```

How can I select the 1st, 4th, and 5th-7th columns?
What I tried:

```
df.iloc[:, [0, 3, np.arange(5,8)]]

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: You may also find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665889/how-to-take-column-slices-of-dataframe-in-pandas/10677896) useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
df.iloc[:, [0, 3] + list(range(5,8))]
```

`[0, 3] + list(range(5,8))` concatenates 2 lists, combining your explicit list with a list derived from your desired range.

Alternatively, you can use [`numpy.r`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to build an indexing array for you:

```
import numpy as np

df.iloc[:, np.r_[0,3,5:8]]

np.r_[0,3,5:8]  # array([0, 3, 5, 6, 7])
```

This would be useful, for example, if you have multiple ranges.

Comment: 2nd approach is exactly what I needed. Thanks