# Returning column from dataframe by name

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have dataframe with given names of columns and I want to to return a column with specified name:

```
name_of_column = 'name1'  # string variable
```

I tried to use this:

```
dataframe.iloc[:, name_of_column]
```

But it did not work. What should I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: welcome as a new programmer. your question already have answers to how to do in the documentation. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html you might not find it immediately, but it's there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take column-slices of dataframe in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665889/how-to-take-column-slices-of-dataframe-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
dataframe[column_name]
```

Will select the column.

`iloc()` method finds an item in pandas by index.

More examples the selecting data you can find in [Pandas Indexing and Selecting Data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) instead of [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and your syntax will work. `iloc` is for indexing by **integer position** (this is what the `i` stands for), while `loc` is for indexing by **label**. So you can use:

```
dataframe.loc[:, name_of_column]
```

Having said this, the more usual way to retrieve a series is to use `__getitem__` directly:

```
dataframe[name_of_column]
```