# Copy a DataFrame to another with 5 min interval

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like copy dataframe df into df2 with 5 mins interval, instead of 1 min.

How to extract the row by a particular interview?

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('sample.txt', names=['Time', 'Index', 'Volume'], delim_whitespace=True)
>>> df.head(20)
                Time   Index  Volume
0   2019/05/16-09:15  27830    2031
1   2019/05/16-09:16  27815     995
2   2019/05/16-09:17  27829     961
3   2019/05/16-09:18  27848     663
4   2019/05/16-09:19  27873     869
5   2019/05/16-09:20  27847     854
6   2019/05/16-09:21  27828     784
7   2019/05/16-09:22  27813     676
8   2019/05/16-09:23  27828     700
9   2019/05/16-09:24  27849     665
10  2019/05/16-09:25  27851     487
11  2019/05/16-09:26  27859     451
12  2019/05/16-09:27  27874     548
13  2019/05/16-09:28  27898    1105
14  2019/05/16-09:29  27907     832
15  2019/05/16-09:30  27897    1470
```

My expected dataframe

```
>>> df2
                Time   Index  Volume
0   2019/05/16-09:15  27830    2031
5   2019/05/16-09:20  27847     854
10  2019/05/16-09:25  27851     487
15  2019/05/16-09:30  27897    1470
.....
```

Comment: you can use splicing. see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665889/how-to-take-column-slices-of-dataframe-in-pandas

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) working with `DatetimeIndex`, so first convert column to `datetime` and then [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df = df.set_index('Time').asfreq('5T').reset_index()
print (df)
                 Time  Index  Volume
0 2019-05-16 09:15:00  27830    2031
1 2019-05-16 09:20:00  27847     854
2 2019-05-16 09:25:00  27851     487
3 2019-05-16 09:30:00  27897    1470
```

If format of datetimes cannot be changed:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df = df.asfreq('5T').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
               Time  Index  Volume
0  2019/05/16-09:15  27830    2031
1  2019/05/16-09:20  27847     854
2  2019/05/16-09:25  27851     487
3  2019/05/16-09:30  27897    1470
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a groupby statement, there is a convienience method for datetime indexing `.resample`

```
 df.set_index('Time').resample('5T').last()
```

produces:

```
Out[156]:
0   2019/05/16-09:15  27830    2031
5   2019/05/16-09:20  27847     854
10  2019/05/16-09:25  27851     487
15  2019/05/16-09:30  27897    1470
```