# how to fetch specific column rang in CSV in python using iloc

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I have a CSV file which has 4 columns and I want fetch only 2nd and 3rd columns in a array using but I'm not able to fetch , always got some wrong set of data , Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd    
dataset = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
x = dataset.iloc[:1 , :1].values
```

can anyone help me how to get them ?

Comment: Use `x = dataset.iloc[: , [1,2]]`

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33997632)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Check out this image]

I hope the above image answers your questions.Upvote if it does :)