# python_slicing I see in some examples we use two bracket but in others we use two I am little confused so how can I use them

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, slice, brackets

When do we use two brackets and when one.

Example:   `Weather[["Min TemperatureF","Mean TemperatureF", "Max TemperatureF"]]`?

I see in some examples we use two brackets but in others we use two. I am a little confused so how can I use them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to take column-slices of dataframe in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665889/how-to-take-column-slices-of-dataframe-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

You use two bracket when you want to return multiple columns e.g

```
Weather[["Min TemperatureF","Mean TemperatureF", "Max TemperatureF"]]
```

You use single brackets when you want to return a single column e.g.

```
Weather["Max TemperatureF"]
```

Here is a good [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665889/how-to-take-column-slices-of-dataframe-in-pandas) on general column slicing of dataframes in pandas