# How to add a new column to a sub-dataframe from pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am starting to work with pandas, so this is probably a pretty obvious question, but I have been struggling with it for a while now and found no solution.

Consider this dataframe:

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
apple = pdr.DataReader('AAPL', data_source='yahoo', 
                      start=datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1), 
                      end=datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1))
```

Now, I can add a new column to this dataframe simply doing:

```
apple['new_column'] = np.arange(apple.shape[0])
```

However, if I usse `iloc` to extract a subdataframe and try to add a new column to the subdataframe:

```
apple_2 = apple.iloc[1:5,:]
apple_2['test2'] = np.arange(4)
```

I get the error message:

```
<stdin>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

What am I doing wrong and how am I supposed to do this in pandas? The error suggests using `.loc`but I do not know how to use it to add new columns.

Comment: Is this error? I think it is a warning.

Comment: @büşraçelik it is a warning but still when the warning appears, I get no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
apple_2 = apple.loc[:, 'High':'Close']
```

this will give you all the columns between 'High' and ' Close' (without close).
But there are also other ways to column-slice a dataframe. You an check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665889/how-to-take-column-slices-of-dataframe-in-pandas).

EDIT:

```
apple_2 = apple.loc[:, 'High':'Close']
#add a new column to apple_2
apple_2['new_column'] = np.arange(apple_2.shape[0])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question was more about how to add a new column rather than performing column-slice on existing columns.

Comment: Something like: apple_2['new_column'] = np.arange(apple_2.shape[0])

Comment: If you execute the very same code from your answer, you will get the error message I was asking about: <stdin>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead. Thank you but this does not answer the question

Comment: I don't know exactly what have you tried, I edit the answer with the code that it's working. The error you are saying is because of using .iloc instead of .loc, so I provide you a way of using .loc, before adding the new column. Then you add the new column taking into account the new shape of the df apple_2.