# pandas column-slices with mypy

Tags: python, pandas, slice, mypy

Lately I've found myself in a strange situation I cannot solve for myself:

Consider this MWE:

```py
import pandas
import numpy as np

data = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 5), columns=list("abcde"))

observations = data.loc[:, :"c"]
features = data.loc[:, "c":]

print(data)
print(observations)
print(features)
```

According to [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44736467/10020441) the slicing itself is done correct and it works in the sense that the correct results are printed.
But when I try to run mypy over it I get this error:

```bash
mypy.exe .\t.py
t.py:1: error: Skipping analyzing "pandas": module is installed, but missing library stubs or py.typed marker
t.py:1: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-imports
t.py:6: error: Slice index must be an integer or None
t.py:7: error: Slice index must be an integer or None
Found 3 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Which is also correct since the slicing is not done with an integer.
How can I either satisfy or disable the `Slice index must be an integer or None` error?

Of course you could use `iloc(:,:3)` to solve this problem, but this feels like a bad practice, since with `iloc` we are depending on the order of the columns (in this example `loc` is also dependent on the ordering, but this is only done to keep the MWE short).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an open issue ([*#GH2410*](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2410)).

As a workaround, you can maybe try with [`get_loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) :

```
col_idx = data.columns.get_loc("c")
​
observations = data.iloc[:, :col_idx+1]
features = data.iloc[:, col_idx:]
```

Output :

```
           a         b         c # <- observations
0   0.269605  0.497063  0.676928
1   0.526765  0.204216  0.748203
2   0.919330  0.059722  0.422413
..       ...       ...       ...
7   0.056050  0.521702  0.727323
8   0.635477  0.145401  0.258166
9   0.041886  0.812769  0.839979

[10 rows x 3 columns]

           c         d         e  # <- features
0   0.676928  0.672298  0.177933
1   0.748203  0.995165  0.136659
2   0.422413  0.222377  0.395179
..       ...       ...       ...
7   0.727323  0.291441  0.056998
8   0.258166  0.219025  0.405838
9   0.839979  0.923173  0.431298

[10 rows x 3 columns]
```